# Uncheck checkbox with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible upon page entry to modify this code to uncheck check box id LOTL even if the page is cached?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function formReset()
{
       document.getElementById("LOTL").reset();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `prop` method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#LOTL').prop('checked', false);
   //  document.getElementById("LOTL").checked = false
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#LOTL').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: Looks like `prop` is the correct way to handle `checked`: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: You are right, I'll have to start using prop for most things instead of attr

Answer (score 1):

Try this to uncheck

```
$(function() {   
    $('#LOTL').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the LOTL element the checkbox or the form?

If it is the checkbox you might try this:

```
$( '#LOTL' ).removeAttr( 'checked' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function formReset(){
       document.getElementById("LOTL").checked = false;
}
```